# Easiest way to update a cell value of a google spreadsheet using curl on linux

Tags: c++, linux, curl, google-api, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet and I'm using the spreadsheet api to get/update cell values. I need to change the value of a cell, I access to the cell with the cell_id, but I don't know how to update the value of that. I've read:
 https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#change_contents_of_a_cell
 but I couldn't understand it.

I'm using the HTTP command `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/<key>/<worksheet_id>/private/full/R2C2` to access to the cell but I don't know how to update it.